# How can I unclick an event in highcharts on the second click

Tags: graph, highcharts, click

I'm trying in this example to unclick a graph when it's displayed under the column chart. In my example, the graph below can only change to other column chart graphs, but I can't revert to the initial state. Is there any way highcharts addresses this directly? Or do I have to include some jquery?

http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/150/

```
$(function () {
    var data = {
        test: [0, 1, 2],
        click: [13, 15, 14],
        other: [100,200 ,100]
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: renderSecond
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{
                y: 100,
                name: 'test'
            }, {
                y: 34,
                name: 'click'
            }, {
                y: 67,
                name: 'other'
            }]
        }]
    });


    function renderSecond(e) {
        var point = this;
        console.log(point);
        $("#detail").highcharts({
            title: {
                text: point.name + ':' + point.y
            },
            series: [{
                data: data[point.name]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? What do you mean saying "unclick an event in highcharts on the second click"? Do you want to hide the second chart somehow?

Comment: Hey Wojciech, sorry, by unclick I mean that when one of the columns is clicked and the graph below is displayed, that on the second click of that same column the graph below "hides" back to the initial state (1st click "unhide", 2nd click "back to hide"). I hope that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is very simple. It can be achieved using a flag to check if the same point was clicked and `chart.destroy()` to remove the chart when it happens.

**Code:**

```
$(function() {
  var secondChart,
    clickedPointId,
    data = {
      test: [0, 1, 2],
      click: [13, 15, 14],
      other: [100, 200, 100]
    },
    chart;

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'bar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        point: {
          events: {
            click: renderSecond
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [{
        y: 100,
        name: 'test'
      }, {
        y: 34,
        name: 'click'
      }, {
        y: 67,
        name: 'other'
      }]
    }]
  });


  function renderSecond(e) {
    var point = this;

    if (clickedPointId !== point.id) {
      clickedPointId = point.id;

      secondChart = Highcharts.chart('detail', {
        title: {
          text: point.name + ':' + point.y
        },
        series: [{
          data: data[point.name]
        }]
      });
    } else {
      clickedPointId = null;
      secondChart.destroy();
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m5ns84xy/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy